# What is the easiest way to delete lots of Heroku apps?

Tags: heroku

I have lots of Heroku apps that I would like to get rid of. Unfortunately, I don't have the original repos. I'm happy to delete them all one-by-one through the web interface. Before I do, is there a quick way to do this using the toolbelt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number, you can use the web interface or create a script using the [Heroku API DELETE/app endpoint](https://api-docs.heroku.com/apps#DELETE/apps).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the below script. It requires that you supply the name of one app you want to keep, with the idea being that if you're just getting started with heroku you might create a bunch of apps while practicing until you get one right, then want to delete all the rest.

```
myApp="$1"
ignore=("===" "<your email address>" "Apps")
allApps=($(heroku apps))

if [[ " ${allApps[@]} " =~ " $myApp " ]]; then
    # if the given app name is a listed app name
    for app in "${allApps[@]}"; do
        if [[ ! "$app" = "$myApp" ]]; then
            if [[ ! " ${ignore[@]} " =~ " $app " ]]; then
                heroku apps:destroy --app $app --confirm $app
            fi
        fi
    done
else
    echo "$1 is not a heroku app"
fi
```